# Regexp - Allow chinese word or N/A ONLY

Tags: regex

```
/^[\u0391-\uFFE5\.\-\,\(\)]*$/
```

Sorry, new to regex.
Had done this to allow only Chinese character.

Then after i Changed

```
/^[\u0391-\uFFE5\.\-\,\(\)(N/A)]*$/
```

Then it allows all Chinese character + A,NA, AN, N/A, A/N
tried to change (N/A), (N/A),(N(/)A) yet all return the same result...

how if i wan only chinese character and exactly "N/A" only??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: This question shows little or no research and is not useful or clear. See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a capturing or non-capturing group.

```
/^(?:[\u0391-\uFFE5.,()-]|N\/A)*$/
```

Comment: illegal character range in index 20?? the error arrow point to the '-' after the 0391